# How to open product from Enovia5 using CATIA VBA in context mode?

Tags: vba, catia

I tried to open a part or a product from ENOVIA5. The issue: I have to open a large number of products using context product mode and there are times CATIA just crashes, and there are times I need to reopen the same products again. This takes a lot of my time.

I tried

`CATIA.Documents.Open("ENOVIA5\FULL_FILE_PATH.EXTENSION")`

`CATIA.Documents.Open("FULL_FILE_PATH.EXTENSION")`

and I get `Document cannot be read` from CATIA. No error from `VBA`. I try to open the root document and the same error message. The same thing happens if I tried to open a different file types

Comment: Open a Catproduct. Loop on each catia.documents. Get path of document. Use catia.documents.open(document.path). This alternative should work, then compare this path with your first path to know why you could not open the document. Be sure you are connected to enovia before trying to open the document.

Comment: @Disvoys, Thanks. I already tried that but same message.